# The Dedekind eta function $\eta(\tau)=q^{\frac{1}{24}} \prod_{n=1}^\infty (1-q^n)$ and $|\tau|^{1/2} |\eta(\tau)|^2$

Tags: conformal-field-theory, dedekind-eta-function

I tried to prove the standard identities of the Dedekind eta function
$$\eta(\tau)=q^{\frac{1}{24}} \prod_{n=1}^\infty (1-q^n),$$
where $q=\exp(2\pi i \tau)$ for some complex number $\tau$, but encountered some challenges.

First,
$$\eta(-\frac{1}{\tau}) =\sqrt{-i\tau}\eta (\tau) $$

I think there's something to do with the $\Gamma$ functions. However, I'm not really sure how to convert the $-\frac{1}{\tau}$ on the exponential back to the $\tau$, and extract a $\sqrt{i\tau}$ on the front.

Second,
$$|\tau|^{1/2} |\eta(\tau)|^2$$
is invariant under $\tau\rightarrow -\frac{1}{\tau}$, where $|\eta(\tau)|^2 = \eta(\tau) \cdot \eta(\bar \tau)$.
I took it from the papers for granted, but when I tried to prove it, I found it was somehow confusing given the first identities.

Could you show how to prove the above two identities, please? I was working on the line of the series expansion through the Euler identities, but it didn't work.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1815323

Comment: @Gary Thank you! That's first half.

Comment: I believe the invariance is under $\tau \to - 1/\tau$.

Comment: @Gary Oh! yes. I changed it.

Comment: $$\left|\tau\right|^{1/2} \left| {\eta (\tau )} \right|^2=\left| {-{\rm i}\tau }\right|^{1/2} \left| {\eta (\tau )} \right|^2=(\left| { -{\rm i}\tau } \right|^{1/4}\left| {\eta(\tau)} \right|)^2=(\left| { - {\rm i}\tau } \right|^{ - 1/4}\left| {-{\rm i}\tau } \right|^{1/2}\left| {\eta (\tau )} \right|)^2=\left| { - {\rm i}\tau } \right|^{-1/2} (\left| { - {\rm i}\tau } \right|^{1/2} \left| {\eta (\tau )}\right|)^2=\left| {-{\rm i}\tau}\right|^{-1/2} \left| {\eta \left({-\frac{1}{\tau }}\right)}\right|^2=\left| {-\frac{1}{\tau}}\right|^{1/2}\left|\eta\left( -\frac{1}{\tau}\right)\right|^2 
$$